# Reading a file line by line using for..in

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa, for-in-loop, fast-enumeration

I'm trying to to read lines one by one from an external txt file (about 180kb) using Objective-C. I have found this piece of code here on SO. The way I understand it this code will put every line in an element right?

```
- (IBAction)start:(id)sender; {
    NSString *fh = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    for (NSArray *line in [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
        NSLog(@"output= %@",line[5]);
    }
}
```

I try to check if it is working by printing a line to my output but nothing happens, what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,

Update:
I made the suggested changes and as it turnout fh is indeed nil. If I make fh a string containing a piece of the text file (including a few \n) it works fine. I checked the file path but that seems allright, So the question now would be how come fh = nil?

```
NSString *fh = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"file:///Users/Mubanga/Documents/Blender/rough2.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if([fh length] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"fh=nil");
}
for (NSString *line in [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
    NSLog(@"output= %@",line);
    }

}
```

Comment: First of all, verify that fh is not nil.

Comment: @MartinR you were right, fh turned out te be nil. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: You might also want to not use `fh` as the name of a variable that does not contain an NSFileHandle. Since it contains a string, I would name it `string`, `str`, or `fileContents` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the required changes from @trojanfoe's answer, your `fh` is `nil`
because the path is wrong. `stringWithContentsOfFile:` expects a simple path, not
a file-URL. It should be:

```
 NSString *fh = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Mubanga/Documents/Blender/rough2.txt" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

Generally, you should use the error parameter:

```
NSError *error;
NSString *fh = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/Mubanga/Documents/Blender/rough2.txt"
                                         encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                            error:&error];
if (fh == nil) {
    NSLog(@"Could not read file: %@", error);
} else {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: The other reason fh could be nil is that the file is not valid UTF-8 data. Check the encoding of your file.

Answer (score 3):

The loop should be:

```
for (NSString *line in [fh componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]) {
    NSLog(@"output= %@",line);
}
```

(`line` will be an `NSString` and the output should be `line`, not `line[5]`).

Comment: Indeed. `componentsSeparatedByString:` returns an array, and the `for` loop *iterates through the objects in the array*. The objects in the array are strings—each string being one of the lines from the original string.

Answer (score 1):

I would do the character input by hand using native C calls. Just [`read()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/read.2.html) into a `char[] buffer` until you hit a newline, then process the buffer. No I won't write the code for you, check out the still-relevant [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language).

Comment: I have to agree. When it comes to parsing files I still prefer standard C. There is nothing wrong with using C as Objective-C is just a superset of C.

Comment: And yet K&R lived in the ASCII age where all users spoke English, or else.  This is no longer the case and `NSString` is better equipped to deal with non-latin characters than plain C is.